# Count the number of pages a pdf file has in each commit

Tags: git, pdf, gitlab

I'm working with a gitlab repository that contains a pdf file whose size in pages I would like to track with each commit. Ideally I'd obtain a table of commit hashes, commit timestamps, and the number of the pages of the file (or any information that I can then use to obtain this number). What's a good way to do this?

Comment: What OS do you use? On *nix you could use pdfinfo to get a number of pages in PDF file.

Comment: What do you you have so far? What specific problem do you encounter in the process?

Comment: I just don't know how to approach the `per commit' side of things. I know how to get the number of pages in a pdf file on my OS (Fedora), but I don't know how to do it in a good way for every version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it with `document.pdf`:

```
git log --oneline document.pdf | cut -d ' ' -f1 | while read x; do git show "$x":document.pdf > /tmp/doc.pdf ; printf "Commit: %s on %s\n" "$x" "$(git show --pretty=%ad -s $x)"; pdfinfo /tmp/doc.pdf | grep Pages; done | column -t ; rm /tmp/doc.pdf
```

Example output:

```
Commit:  2f277b0  on  Tue  Aug  27  22:42:26  2019  +0200
Pages:   550
Commit:  e1d1abb  on  Tue  Aug  27  22:42:15  2019  +0200
Pages:   551
Commit:  89b3d35  on  Tue  Aug  27  22:41:48  2019  +0200
Pages:   552
```

Notice that newest commit will be shown first, if you want to change
the order use `git log --reverse`.

Comment: Ah yes I see what's going on, thank you! I notice you have to download the file for each commit, so I'm guessing the page count was not somehow saved with the commits themselves.

Comment: "Download" is not the correct term here, you simple need a file to use with `pdfinfo`. Git itself doesn't care about types of your file and if you specifically do not save number of pages in each commit, either in a commit message or note, it will not be saved anywhere.